# traverse upward on a directory structure until it gets to the file system top level

Tags: python, traversal

I have already created a script which sets "**FLAG**" after backup on uppermost level of each directory.

now I need a script that could be run "in any directory" and that would tell me "when the last successful backup ran" by reading the last modification time of the "**FLAG**".

Of course I can also manually find out on what file system my current directory is located and then go up in the directory hierarchy until I get to the file system's top level directory and find the flag file there but that is not very convenient. The command that I would like to write would do the same thing, but automatically.

1) I do not know how to do the part where it traverses upward on a directory structure until it gets to the file system top level.

2) reading the Flag time might work sth like this:

```
import time
fileTileInSeconds = os.path.getmtime("FLAG")   (not sure)
ModDate = time.localtime(fileTileInSeconds)
print ModDate.tm_year,ModDate.tm_mon,ModDate.tm_mday,ModDate.tm_hour,ModDate.tm_min,ModDate.tm_sec
quit()
```

Any idea/suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.parent` to go up the directory tree, and use `os.stat` to see which device each directory is on. When the device changes, you have crossed the boundary of the filesystem. Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import stat
import sys

def find_mount(path):
    path = os.path.realpath(path)
    s = os.stat(path)[stat.ST_DEV]
    ps = s
    while path != '/' and ps == s:
        parent = os.path.dirname(path)
        ps = os.stat(parent)[stat.ST_DEV]
        if ps == s:
            path = parent
    return path

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for path in sys.argv[1:]:
        print find_mount(path)
```